# Cannot configure jacoco on sonar for ant projects

Tags: sonarqube

I have downloaded jacoco from internet and copied the folder under my source directory inside a folder named reports now i have the following

```
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root  root  4096 Oct 15 15:03 .
drwxrwxr-x. 6 build build 4096 Oct 15 14:52 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root  root  4096 Oct  7 00:52 coverage
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root  root  4096 Oct  7 01:06 doc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root  3250 Oct  7 01:06 index.html
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root  root  4096 Oct  7 01:06 lib
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root  root  4096 Oct 15 15:02 META-INF
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root  root  4096 Oct  7 01:06 test
```

But on the following link 
    https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/it/sonar-runner/it-jacoco-sonar-runner/reports

i see jacoco.exec added under reports i am confused how do i use jacoco now.

I have jenkins installed and using sonar for code quality analysis where i want to use jacoco for my java code. Also i am using Ant and executing sonar-runner to generate sonar analysis.

please could someone help me so as how do i get jacoco.exec??

Comment: For a working exmaple, go here:  http://itestfirst.wordpress.com/2014/10/15/ant-sonar-and-jacoco-working-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ant to build your projects, then you should rather have a look at the following example projects:

- JaCoCo for unit tests with Ant: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/ut/ant
- JaCoCo for integration tests with Ant: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/it/ant/it-jacoco-ant

Comment: Only if your Ant script did everything to prepare the analysis: compile sources and tests, run the unit tests with the correct config to generate XML reports for tests AND coverage. Basically, use the examples I provided but just remove the <sonar:sonar> task, and use Jenkins to use the reports generated by your Ant build script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i really have a problem here i already have an ant script which compiles but no unit cases have been written inside it, so what do i do now should i write a seperate build.xml and call the same from the original or how should i proceed?

Comment: As I told you, modify your Ant script to do like what's done in the example application